# What is the most simple way to write a number in the middle of a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a series of panels and a click event on the panel. Originally I had labels in the panel but it made things too cluttered and complicated my click event. Is there anyway I can just write text in the center of the panel because by placing a label in the middle it interferes with the click. All I need is a square/rectangle like object that I can a)dock b)change the color c)put dynamic text in the middle. Maybe I am overlooking a control preferable to panel?

Comment: You could subscribe to the panel's `Paint` event, and draw directly on it.

Comment: Right now I am trying to make the code as concise as possible. I have 100 panels and I assigned them all to the same event so through sender I can dynamically make them all behave the same way. Could you post an answer demonstrating the most concise way to draw text in the center of the panel that I can repeat in a for loop throughout 100 panels for example. Then of course I plan on changing this text on a single click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Paint event to the `Panel(s)` and draw number as string using `DrawString` method of the `Graphics` class. Check this code as an example:

```
//Add the Paint event, you can set the same handler for each panel you are using
panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel1_Paint);

//create the font with size you want to use, measure the string with that font 
//and the Graphics class, calculate the origin point and draw your number:

 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
       Panel p = (Panel)sender;
       Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"),30);
       string number = "10";
       SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(number, font);
       PointF origin = new PointF(p.Width/2 - textSize.Width/2, p.Height/2 - textSize.Height/2);
       e.Graphics.DrawString("10", font, Brushes.Black, origin);
 }
```

Since this code is executing very often, you would might want to declare and instantiate the the `Font` outside of the `Paint` handler:

```
 Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"),30);
 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
       Panel p = (Panel)sender;
       string number = "10";
       SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(number, font);
       PointF origin = new PointF(p.Width/2 - textSize.Width/2, p.Height/2 - textSize.Height/2);
       e.Graphics.DrawString("10", font, Brushes.Black, origin);
 }
```

EDIT:

Added after the OP's comment:
Finding the largest font size for which the string still fits into the Panel

```
string number = "10";
float emSize = 10f;
SizeF textSize = SizeF.Empty;
Font font = null;
do
{
     emSize++;
     font = new System.Drawing.Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"), emSize);
     textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(number, font);
}
while (panel1.Width > textSize.Width && panel1.Height > textSize.Height);
font = new System.Drawing.Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"), --emSize);
```

Disclaimer: I didn't take into account `float` to `int` casting, but that is something that should be taken care of also.

Comment: Very nice stuff! Thank you! Never used the DrawString method before! Also I notice you have a MeasureString method which makes me extremely curious. Could you demonstrate for me a way to use MeasureString to dynamically fit the font size in the Panel(so for example it would pick a font size that allowed it to fill as much as possible without overflowing text? I am confused as to exactly how that plays in and if that would be possible.

Comment: Basically, you would need to instantiate fonts with different sizes and measure the sting you want. Then check the size of the string and the size of the Panel and do it while it still fits the Panel. Increment the size of the font and the first time i overflows, use the last one that fitted.

Comment: This is really great. After playing with this I am going to be able to integrate my original design into this. This really makes life so much easier I don't think I will ever use a label ever again in any of my programs...

Comment: Don't forget that label is control with all of its advantages like events and properties. Check the simplest solution I added to the answer from the top of my head. It is not the best one, but assuming that you are not going to do this regularly, it will be fine.

Comment: Hmm thought about one feature of the label that is lacking here. Is there a way I can make a white backdrop around the string?

Comment: Instances of the Font class should be disposed when they won't be used anymore - that's not the case in this answer currently

Comment: The following code allows me to draw a rectangle around my string `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, origin.X, origin.Y, textSize.Width, textSize.Height);`
Onkelborg care to go into more detail for someone passing by?